# Count how many unique characters two strings share with each other

Tags: php, string, function

I have written a PHP function that takes two strings as parameters `$str1` and `$str2`.

Now I want to count how many unique characters those two strings share. So for example:

```
$str1 = "stringstring1";
$str2 = "stringstring2";
```

In this example they share 6 unique characters, which are: `s,t,r,i,n,g`.

So here is my current code:

```
<?php

    function compare($str1, $str2){
        $cmp = 0;

        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str1); $i++){

            for($j = 0; $j < strlen($str2); $j++){
                if($str1[$i] == $str2[$j]) 
                    $cmp++;
            }

       }

        echo "Number of characters in common: ".$cmp."<br />";
    }

    compare("stringstring1", "stringstring2");

?>
```

Right now the problem is that it gives me the output 24 instead of 6. And I don't see where I went wrong, that it outputs 24 instead of 6?

Comment: You can use a hastable. Your complexity right now is O(n**2), with hash table you can have it in O(n). use hashtable.

Comment: I would use the array functions. Explode - array_unique - array_intersect - count

Comment: 1) Indent your code and use spaces to make your code more readable 2) Right now you go through the entire second string for each character of the first string. So you compare `s`(from string1) to `stringstring2`(string2) and then it will find the character two times. To solve this you want to keep track of which characters you already used. For example you could use an array and put all unique characters which both strings have in it and check before you increment `$cmp` if the character is already in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to store the characters in an array which both strings share and then check if you already counted a character before you increment `$cmp`.

Here is the rewritten code:

```
function compare($str1, $str2){
    $cmp = 0;
    $used_letter = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str1); $i++){

        for($j = 0; $j < strlen($str2); $j++){
            if($str1[$i] == $str2[$j]) 
                if(!in_array($str1[$i], $used_letter)){
                    $cmp++;
                    $used_letter[$cmp] = $str1[$i];
                }
        }
    }

    echo "Number of characters in common: " . $cmp . "<br />";

}

compare("stringstring1","stringstring2");
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @Vaibhav Bhanushali

Comment: I would use `{}` for the first if statement in your answer to make it clear, what exactly in the if statement is.

Comment: Seems i missed that out :( .@Rizier123

Comment: @Rizier123 it was just the first time I asked a question and I didn't know these rules

Comment: @novex No problem, that is why I write it so you can learn it :) Also you can take a quick [tour] and get a quick overview of this site. And if you didn't already read it see [ask] just for the next question to make it even better.

Comment: Okay, @Rizier123 your suggestions are going to be very useful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good , however, if you want to compare multiple strings and extract the common characters, here is another solution:

```
$str1 = "stringstring1";
$str2 = "stringstring2";
$str3 = "stringstring3";
$computed = array_merge_recursive(array_count_values(str_split($str1)), array_count_values(str_split($str2)), array_count_values(str_split($str3)));
$commons = array();
foreach ($computed as $key => $el) {
    if (is_array($el)) 
        $commons[] = $key;
}

/*commons*/
["s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g"]
```

Comment: I appreciate your help @cpugourou :D